# Getting CORS Error for Image in PWA

Tags: magento2, image, pwa, pwa-studio, cors

I am facing a CORS issue while fetching image in PWA Studio..Image works fine in magento root but while fetching with same URL in pwa it is giving cors error in console..

The Code of the page is below:

```
export default function BlogDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { fetched } = UseBlogdetails(id);
    return (
                   ..........
                    <img src={`http://127.0.0.1/training/magento246/pub/media/blog/img/${fetched?.image}`} />
               ..........
```

Below is the path of image made in developer tools..It is Perfect..

[image]

and getting error as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solution..It was the issue of chrome that it doesn't accept request from local i.e,from site having http server.. so tried below:

```
chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests
```

and disabled this tab:**Block insecure private network requests**

and the issue got solved..

but it works fine without disabling in other browser..

Thanks!!